# Where files are used if path entered by hand

Tags: 8, files

I am brining a 100 or so static pages into my drupal install here. We are pasting the content from the static site into the body of a content type. I am using ICME to upload the images and documents. Unless I directly link from ICME to the document, I've noticed it does not record as being used (/admin/content/files > USED IN). Is there a batch script to run to check if a file is used somehow?

We are adding the files, but only updating the path via code editor find and replace... I do not want to hightlight each image and find the file in Drupal. The files are being recorded in the system as IMCE does that and if we do actually use the ckeditor IMCE link it does show as used. Just to emphasize that.

Comment: This will never happen because text in an editor is simply HTML and not recorded by Drupal as being a true file entity, unless you are embedding an entity. Therefore, it has no idea it exists.

Answer (score 0):

[inline_image_to_field](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_image_to_field) module promises turn your inline images into an image field (image entities).

> This module will take images that are embedded (copy/paste) or were uploaded via the wysiwyg and attach them to an image field.

This way you can have your Drupal installation being fully aware of any such images and take advantage of any **file or image entity** related modules.

**DISCLAIMER:** I have not used this module and it is new module with not many installs so use with caution on your DEV environment before commiting to your LIVE environment